# Post saves filename as array;jpg instead of input name

Tags: php, post, user-input

Trying to save a jpg file to server with the name from an input box but gets saved as Array.jpg

Contents of html file:

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
```

Contents of php file:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];

$location = "upload/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

$filename = ['datepicker'].'.jpg';
echo $_REQUEST['datepicker'];

$file = $location . $filename;

file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
```

Script from the html:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

    // Get base64URL
    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {image: base64URL},
       success: function(data){
       console.log('Upload successfully');
       }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

no error messages , just saves with wrong name.

Have now tried:

```
$filename = ['datepicker']; - saves as: Array (no extension).  
$filename = $_POST['datepicker']; (nothing gets saved at all).   
$filename = $_POST['datepicker'].'.jpg'; (saves as .jpg (just extension, no file name).   
$filename = $_FILES['datepicker']['name'];  (nothing gets saved at all).   
$filename = $datepicker;   (nothing gets saved at all).   
$filename = "screenshot_".uniqid().'.jpg'; saved as screenshot_5d40158a1dad5.jpg
```

It seems to me that the form name field, datepicker, is not available to the php file at all.
Maybe this is because the call (or whatever you call it) to the php file is wrapped in javascript tags? I dont know. Just getting frustrated after 24 hours of trying to get this to work.

I think I have to pass form name field, datepicker, to the ajax code and then use it in the php file.
Anyone know how to amend my code to do this?

I have now resolved this. I had to amend the javascript in the html to include a var with the vale from the text input box and update the ajax to include it in the data line.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

    // Get base64URL
    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
    var val1 = $('#datepicker').val();

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       //data: {image: base64URL, name: datepicker},
       data: {image: base64URL, datepicker: val1},
       success: function(data){
       console.log('Upload successfully');
       }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Then I had to update the php file with the file name to include the txt data from the form in the filename:

```
<?php 

$image = $_POST['image'];

$location = "upload/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

$filename = $_POST['datepicker'].'.jpg';

$file = $location . $filename;

file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

?>
```

Comment: You are collecting the name as array if you use post take as $_POST[“name”] or fir get $_GET[“name”] for basic php

Comment: You are actively _creating_ an array here, `['datepicker']` - that is an array containing one element, the string `datepicker`. Since you then try to concatenate this with the suffix `.jpg`, the array gets forcefully converted into a string, and the result of that is always the _word_ “Array”.

Comment: Thank you samuhay, I tried  $_POST[“name”] using the example below but this only saved as .jpg. I tried amending the line to use $_GET[“name”] ($_GET['datepicker'].'.jpg';) but nothing got uploaded at all.

Comment: Thanks misorude.I did not know this was creating an array. i am *very* new to this. An array never needs to be created as it is always just the one file. Almost all examples I looked at gave this method, though just for one file (but they were not adding the ext).

Comment: I added the script code from the html file to the original post

Comment: When I asked the developer of original code how to do this he answered with the following but I did not understand it at all;   You need to add echo $filename at the end of ajaxfile.php and you can retrieve it from AJAX success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this. I had to amend the javascript in the html to include a var with the value from the text input box and update the ajax to include it in the data line.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

    // Get base64URL
    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
    var val1 = $('#datepicker').val();

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       //data: {image: base64URL, name: datepicker},
       data: {image: base64URL, datepicker: val1},
       success: function(data){
       console.log('Upload successfully');
       }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Then I had to update the php file with the file name to include the txt data from the form in the filename:

```
<?php 

$image = $_POST['image'];

$location = "upload/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

$filename = $_POST['datepicker'].'.jpg';

$file = $location . $filename;

file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$filename = $_POST['datepicker'].'.jpg';

Comment: Thanks Ryan, very much but this just saves it as .jpg

Comment: can you give me a result of var_dump($_POST['datepicker']); ?

Comment: I could if I knew where to put it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the ajax and javascript (as the txt from the input box was not being sent to the php at all) and was then able to use your example in the php and is all working now. See my updated original post with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is not a good way to store a file in a PHP.

you should prefix current date and some random number generated by PHP to image name before storing the image because if two images are to be stored in the same folder on server's first image will be overwritten and the second file will be stored in its place making the first image to be disappeared completely

try prefixing " `date('Ymdhis').rand(100000,999999)` " to your image file and use `$_FILES['something']['name']` and `$_FILES['something']['tmp_name']` to get name and temperary name of the image respectively to store image

Comment: Thank you Abdul. The file will be saved with the date. this is a simple timesheet application where a week of expected working hours is entered. This almost always changes so the file will need to be overwritten at least once.